# How to pass multiple attributes to WebApi?

Tags: vb.net, api, asp.net-web-api

I have a **webapi** made in **VB.NET** where I can get all data, data by month and data by year. Now I am trying to add the functionality to get data by data-range, in the constructor the method looks as the following:

```
Public Function TotaliDataData(ByVal inizio As String, ByVal fine As String) As IEnumerable(Of Totali)
    Dim SQLConnect As String = "Server=127.0.0.1;Port=3306;Database=00168780351;Uid=root;Pwd=block;"
    Dim cn As New MySqlConnection(SQLConnect)
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT NPV_TT, NCASSA_TT, DATA_TT, AZZ_TT, SUM(NSC_TT) AS NSC_TT, SUM(VENDITE_TT) AS VENDITE_TT, RESI_TT, ANNULLI_TT, SCONTI_TT, FATTURE_TT, NC_TT FROM totali WHERE DATA_TT BETWEEN '" & inizio & "' AND  '" & fine & "' GROUP BY MONTH(DATA_TT);", cn)
    cn.Open()
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    Dim totali As List(Of Totali) = ConvertReader(reader)
    cn.Dispose()
    Return totali
End Function
```

Here is my TotaliController.VB:

```
Public Class TotaliController
    Inherits ApiController

    Public Function GetTotali() As IEnumerable(Of Totali)
        Dim Totali As Totali = New Totali
        Return Totali.GetTotali()
    End Function

    Public Function GetTotaliByYear(ByVal anno As String) As IEnumerable(Of Totali)
        Dim Totali As Totali = New Totali
        Return Totali.TotaliAnno(anno)
    End Function

    Public Function GetTotaliByMonth(ByVal mese As String) As IEnumerable(Of Totali)
        Dim Totali As Totali = New Totali
        Return Totali.TotaliMese(mese)
    End Function

    Public Function TotaliDataData(ByVal inizio As String, ByVal fine As String) As IEnumerable(Of Totali)
        Dim Totali As Totali = New Totali
        Return Totali.TotaliDataData(inizio, fine)
    End Function

    Public Function GetDetails(ByVal annod As String) As IEnumerable(Of Totali)
        Dim Totali As Totali = New Totali
        Return Totali.GetDetails(annod)
    End Function

End Class
```

Then I was trying to call `localhost:port/api/totali/?inizio=2019-11-10&fine=2019-12-20` but it doesn't enter even inside the debug of controller while if I try to get data by month or year with single parameter it works fine..

So how could I pass multiple parameters to WebApi?

UPDATE:

When I try to run `localhost:port/api/totali/?inizio=2019-11-10&fine=2019-12-20` it calls the default GetTotali() method from controller which returns all data from the DB.

Global:

```
Public Class WebApiApplication
    Inherits System.Web.HttpApplication

    Protected Sub Application_Start()
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(AddressOf WebApiConfig.Register)
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.
            JsonFormatter.MediaTypeMappings.Add(New RequestHeaderMapping("Accept", "text/html", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase, True, "application/json"))
    End Sub

End Class
```

WebApiConfig

```
Public Module WebApiConfig
    Public Sub Register(ByVal config As HttpConfiguration)
        ' Servizi e configurazione dell'API Web

        ' Route dell'API Web
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name:="DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults:=New With {.id = RouteParameter.Optional}
        )
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: What does happen when you call that URL? Does it call another method in the controller? Return 404?

Comment: @theduck updated the question, it call the default GetTotali()

Comment: Your example works ok for me. Do you have any routing that might be affecting the routing in this controller? (For instance in Global.asax.vb)

Comment: @theduck i've just added Global and WebApiConfig code the only one think i've added is that the data will be parsed as JSON instead of XML in Global

Comment: @theduck solved the problem, the issue was that there have to be a REST prefix in controller method name

Comment: It looks like you've got a great big SQL injection attack vulnerability there. You need to use SQL parameters instead of concatenating the values into the query string.

Comment: @AndrewMorton actually when the data is processed i accurately format passed data to prevent sql injection

Comment: @IgorMytyuk Well, OK then, I guess you don't want the performance improvements that come along with it too. Also, you need to use `cn.Dispose()`, or you could use the [`Using Statement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) to take care of the disposal of unmanaged resources for you.

Comment: @AndrewMorton instead of passing parameters as quary string how can i pass them as SQL parameters? (Actually i was yet using Dispose() after each sql operation)

Comment: @IgorMytyuk Although the dates do indeed need to be serialised into strings in the query string, I would expect them to be validated and parsed into datetimes before they are used anywhere else in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently methods names in WebApi controller have to start with REST prefix so by changing the name of method `TotaliDataData` to `GetTotaliDataData` solved the problem.